# Count the number of points of a multipoint-feature

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, spatial-analysis, multipoint

I try to use the fieldcalculator in QGIS 2.18 to count the number of points of a multipoint-feature. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to contain the code you have attempted to use (as text, but a screenshot can be a useful supplement) and a description of the error message (again, as text) or unwanted behavior.